# Fetch value from xml element which is enclosed with CDATA through awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am using awk command to fetch values from xml elements. Using below command

```
$(awk -F "[><]" '/'$tag_name'/{print $3}' $FILE_NAME | sort | uniq)
```

Here

1. File_name: XML File.
2. tag_name: name of xml element whose value we
   need.

Sample XML

```
  <item>
    <tag1>test</tag1>
    <tag2><![CDATA[cdata_test]]></tag2>
  </item>
```

One of the tag in xml contains CDATA. For that script is not working as expected.

When I tried to print it is printing blank.

Comment: By "not working as expected" do you mean you're getting an error? You're getting the wrong output?  What does the XML file look like? Not that using traditional text processing tools (`awk`/`sed`/etc) to parse XML can be difficult; you're usually better off using tools designed to parse XML.

Comment: Please provide a significant sample of your XML input, the output you get and the output you want.

Comment: Just added @larsks

Comment: [edit] your question to show us the value of `tag_name`. (also hint: count the `>` and `<`s on the CDATA line to see where `$3` occurs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As xmlstarlet is not installed on my machine.

I used sed prior to my awk command as follows and that works for me.

`$(sed -e 's/<![CDATA[//g; s/]]>//g' ${FILE_NAME} | awk -F "[><]" '/'$tag_name'/{print $3}' | sort | uniq)`

Also, If anybody has any other solution. That too is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a specific tool as AWK, not aware of the XML specificities, I suggest you to use `xmlstarlet` for selecting the nodes you want. For instance:

```
xmlstarlet select -t -v '//tag1' -n input.xml
```

will give as result:

```
test
```

Issuing:

```
xmlstarlet select -t -v '//tag2' -n input.xml
```

gives as output:

```
cdata_test
```

If you don't need the newline at the end of the returned string, just remove the `-n` from the options of the `xmlstarlet` command.

Keep it simple.

Comment: xmlstarlet this is not installed. Also, for me this work
values=$(sed -e 's/<!\[CDATA\[//g; s/\]\]>//g' ${FILE_NAME} | awk -F "[><]" '/'$tag_name'/{print $3}' | sort | uniq)